# Check if mouse is hovering on any object

Tags: jquery, hover, onmouseout

I have a jQuery animation **example here**: http://jsfiddle.net/p7Eta/

I would like **all** the titles to pop out if the mouse is not within the container div at all. I have tried to do something like:

```
$("#container").mouseout(

     function() {
    //slides spans up
    $('.popup').stop().animate({
        bottom: 0 + 'px'
    });

});
```

But it does not work with the prior animations. What is the correct way to achieve this effect?

**EDIT:** I'd like something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/RE3XK/ but on mouseover I'd like the individual span titles to pop up like in the first example instead of having them all dissapear

Comment: Gah, jsfiddle, why won't you load? My example is basically working...

Comment: I know, I'm waiting on it too :(

Comment: It's up now. Why does it die so often...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, jsFiddle cooperated...

I'm doing something hacky, but it's the only way that I could get it to work. I had to add a `.hover` class to the currently hovered element, as my code doesn't work properly without it.
Just don't look at the code, and it'll look nice!

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/p7Eta/41/

And the code:

```
// JavaScript Document

//When div.popup is moused over moused over
$("#slider div.block").hover(

function() {

    //slides spans up
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
    $(this).find('span').stop().animate({
        bottom: '0px'
    });
}, function() {
$(this).removeClass('hovered');
    //slides spans down
    $(this).find('span').stop().animate({
        bottom: '-200px'
    });
});

$('#container').hover(function() {
    $('#slider div.block:not(.hovered) span').animate({
        bottom: '-200px'
    });
}, function() {
    $('#slider div.block span').stop().animate({
        bottom: '0px'
    });
});
```

Comment: ahhh yes this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I never thought about adding classes because I thought the code would get messy yet yours is organized. Thanks so much =)

Comment: No problem. You could probably condense this even more (making the statements one-liners, but I'm too lazy to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this.

### Check working example http://jsfiddle.net/p7Eta/8/

**Update**

```
$("#slider div.popup").hover(
function() {

    //slides spans up
    $('span', this).animate({
        bottom: 0 + 'px'
    });
}, function() {

    //slides spans down
    $('span', this).animate({
        bottom: '-' + 200 + 'px'
    });
});

$(document).mouseover(
function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $('#slider div.popup').find(' span').animate({
        bottom: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Uhm no not really. Isn't that just a reverse of my animation? I'd like it the way its set up right now but when the mouse isn't on any of the elements, hence outside the container div, the titles will all pop up

Comment: @Hussein thanks for looking at it and it's so close to what I want. Is there some possible way to have all the titles except the one being moused over slide down? I've tried directly animating this by sliding down all the titles that aren't active when a title is moused over but the animation gets choppy

Comment: Really? I'm doing just that (animating a bunch at a time), and the tiles seem to slide quite nicely for me. Do the other animations work properly for you?

Comment: @ima jsfiddle was down, couldn't get back to you on time. Glad you got your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I +1 ed you though =)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're going for something along the lines of [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/EEexe/), am I right? The only issue with the way I tried it, is that the element you're entering on, also slides down (which it shouldn't, I guess).

Comment: I just looked at your example and It worked fairly well. Why are all the margins blue >_>. Anyways +1 for being the first to understand what I wanted and having an almost working example

Comment: Sorry, tried to see if adding padding to #slide would solve the 'panel is hover but still manages to slide away'-issue

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this... which actually stops the animations before resetting it. http://jsfiddle.net/NDtMW/

Comment: How is this different from the example that the OP posted?

Comment: when the mouse leaves the item, the moving piece does not continue to the top, but stops and re-animates downward.

Answer (score -1):

Please clarify what you're asking for.  Do you

- want the animations to continuously so they're in constant motion whenever they're not hovered on?
- want them to be at the motion-up state whenever they're not hovered on?

BTW, your original script only works in IE.  If you're only concerned with one browser, please say so in the future.  IE users are probably the minority on SO.